# Oracle Cloud console connection what is the username and password to be used here?

Tags: ssh, iptables, vnc, ubuntu-20.04, oracle-linux

I've been trying out Oracle's Cloud Service after my AWS trial expired, and I've setup a VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro instance with Ubuntu 20.04.

I was trying to change the default SSH port from 22 to 4545, and added it to the iptables using: `$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4545 -j ACCEPT anywhere`, and saved and reloaded iptables.

I then made changes to the `sshd_config` file by uncommenting `#Port 22` and changing it to `PORT 4545`, and restarting the ssh server.

Even after all of that I cannot connect using port 4545 and PUTTY.

I was advised to connect using a `Serial Connection` or `Connect using VNC` using `Oracle's Console Connection` method, but both methods prompt me for a username and password.

I've seen many people connect using VNC user without using a login and password, but in my case it keeps asking me for one.

What am I doing wrong here? What is my username and password? I've tried using ubuntu as the username and a blank password and many other username and password combinations, but none work.

Can anyone help?

[image]